# How to generate seo friendly URLs use .htaccess with PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use GET in `index.php`:

```
$request=isset($_GET['m']) && $_GET['m']!='';
$requestFile=isset($_GET['files']) && $_GET['files']!='';
```

My link is in the format: `localhost:81/Template/index.php?m=index&files=Acc`.

How do I use a `.htaccess` file or PHP to rewrite to: `localhost:81/Template/Acc/index.html or php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Template/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /index.php?m=$2&files=$1 [L]
```

To obtain your page from:

```
localhost:81/Template/Acc/index.html
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You have to enter your pretty formed url by yourself.